# Why does this group_by / count query return an array of tuples?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm running:

```
db.session.query(func.count(db.model.id)).group_by(func.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H",  db.model.created_at)).all()
```

which returns:

```
[(2,), (2,), (1,), (4,)]
```

The numbers correctly correspond to the number of items per hour - but why the tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every query returns a table-like result with a fixed number of columns and an arbitrary number of rows.
This is true even if there is only a single column or a single row; if you omitted the `group_by`, it would return a single row (a list) with a single column (a tuple):

```
[(9,)]
```

Comment: Thanks. Here's how I'm dealing with it: `hourly = [i[0] for i in hourly]`